# get pandas rows with same specific word in two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
     data1                 data2
0   overall_phase1_b3     overall_phase1_b5
1   overall_phase2_b3     overall_phase5_b5
2   overall_phase3_b3     overall_phase3_b5
```

My question is how can I get the dataframe rows with matching phase number? If I have `phase1` in `data1` column, I should have `phase1` in `data2` column.

Desired Output as below

```
       data1                 data2
0   overall_phase1_b3     overall_phase1_b5
1   overall_phase3_b3     overall_phase3_b5
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use `regex`? Since you do not really need regex for this job

Comment: Thanks for comment @ko3, I removed the word `regex` in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `regex` to achieve this. You can use something like this instead:

```py
df[df.data1.str.split("_", expand=True)[1] == df.data2.str.split("_", expand=True)[1]]


------------------------------------------
    data1               data2
0   overall_phase1_b3   overall_phase1_b5
2   overall_phase3_b3   overall_phase3_b5
------------------------------------------
```

What this does is basically to split the columns `data1` and `data2` by '_' and then it compares the second value (including 'phasex') of the extended data frames in both columns. The comparison gives you a mask that can be used to reduce your data.

Answer (score 2):

Since we are dealing with Pandas, I'll provide you the simple answer.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["data1","data2"])
data1 = ['overall_phase1_b3','overall_phase1_b3','overall_phase3_b3']
data2 = ['overall_phase1_b5','overall_phase5_b5','overall_phase3_b5']
df['data1'] = data1
df['data2'] = data2
df
```

The above code will generate you the Pandas Dataframe for the given data.

```
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=["data1","data2"])
result_d1 = []
result_d2 = []
for i,j in df.iterrows():
    if j.data1.split('_')[1][-1] == j.data2.split('_')[1][-1]:
        result_d1.append(j.data1)
        result_d2.append(j.data2)
result['data1'] = result_d1
result['data2'] = result_d2
result
```

After looking your data, we can use the String Split method to compare the phase number with the respective rows that'll tell you the matching phases across each rows. If you don't want to store the result in a DataFrame, better to use **print** statement instead of pushing the results in a DataFrame.

Nice Question though, happy coding ..!

Answer (score 1):

another approach but quite similar:

```
# extract phase numberes and compare
df[df.data1.str.extract('(\d+)')[0]==df.data2.str.extract('(\d+)')[0]]

>>>out
'''
               data1              data2
0  overall_phase1_b3  overall_phase1_b5
2  overall_phase3_b3  overall_phase3_b5
```